# Mysql ORDER BY RAND()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table storing the usage count of topics used, for each subsequent request increases the usage count. I have added a query to return the least used topic.

```
      SELECT b.body, n.nid
      FROM node n
      LEFT JOIN body b ON n.nid = b.entity_id
      LEFT JOIN topic_usage u ON n.nid = u.entity_id
      LEFT JOIN reference r ON n.nid = r.entity_id
        AND (
          r.entity_type =  'node'
        AND
          r.deleted =  '0'
        )
      WHERE n.type = :type
      AND n.status = 1
      AND r.target_id= :id
      ORDER BY u.field_topic_usage_value ASC LIMIT 0,1
```

Example table

```
nid | Usage Count
-----------------
 1  | 0
 2  | 0
 3  | 0
 4  | 1
```

The above query works fine to return the lowest used topic. But the requirement is to apply `RAND()` on the lowest usage.

As per the above example table, the query should do a `rand()` where usage count is 0.

I can write 2 queries, first one gets the lowest count and second query does the `rand()` on that count but can that be combined into 1 ?

Thank you.

Solution 1 @fancypants

```
      SELECT b.body, node.nid
      FROM node 
      LEFT JOIN body ON n.nid = body.entity_id 
      LEFT JOIN topic_usage ON n.nid = u.entity_id 
      LEFT JOIN field_data_field_issue_reference r ON node.nid = f.entity_id , 
        ( select @min := ( 
            SELECT min(f.usage_value) from node n 
            LEFT JOIN field_data_field_topic_usage ON n.nid = f.entity_id 
           )
        ) var_init_subquery 
      AND node.status = 1 
      AND f.field_issue_reference_target_id = 708 
      order by f.usage_value, if(f.usage_value=@min, rand(), node.nid) 
      LIMIT 0,1
```

Solution 2 @Hitesh

```
    SELECT b.body, node.nid
    FROM node
    LEFT JOIN body ON node.nid = b.entity_id
    LEFT JOIN topic_usage ON node.nid = f.entity_id
    LEFT JOIN issue_reference f ON node.nid = f.entity_id
      AND (
        f.entity_type =  'node'
      AND
        f.deleted =  '0'
      )
    WHERE node.type = 'issue_paragraphs'
    AND node.status = 1
    AND f.field_issue_reference_target_id  = 708
    GROUP BY node.nid having f.usage_value=min(f.usage_value)
    ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use Group by and having clause for selections and then use order by rand(). For example i am writing you query as following. My query may be wrong on based on column selections but i am tring to focus on approch.

```
 SELECT b.body, n.nid
      FROM node n
      LEFT JOIN body b ON n.nid = b.entity_id
      LEFT JOIN topic_usage u ON n.nid = u.entity_id
      LEFT JOIN reference r ON n.nid = r.entity_id
        AND (
          r.entity_type =  'node'
        AND
          r.deleted =  '0'
        )
      WHERE n.type = :type
      AND n.status = 1
      AND r.target_id= :id
      GROUP BY n.nid having u.field_topic_usage_value=min(u.field_topic_usage_value)
      ORDER BY rand()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hitesh, yes, group by and having solves it. tested it and working all good.

Comment: @DeepakML Your requirement was, to write it in one query. This way you have to execute 2 times, one time with having clause and order by rand, one time without having and order by whatever. You might want to have a look at my answer again.

Answer (score 2):

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`a` int, `b` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`a`, `b`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 0),
    (4, 0),
    (5, 1),
    (6, 0)
;
```

**Query:**

```
select
*
from
t
order by b, if(b=0, rand(), a)
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe9c7/1/0)

Every time you execute it, `a` column is ordered random for entries where `b` is `0` and ordered by `a` where `b` is not `0`.

To have it working for your minimum, you could simply use [variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html):

```
select
a, b
from
t
, (select @min := (select min(b) from t)) var_init_subquery
order by b, if(b=@min, rand(), a)
```

- again, [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe9c7/3/0)

Comment: Thank you for the response, the query is assuming b remains 0, but the topic usage are going to increase and subsequently b=1 will become the next lowest count.

Comment: @DeepakML I don't have the time right now, to inspect your query, but I adjusted my answer to get you the idea. Adjust it to your query and it should definitely work.

Comment: I have updated my question with the 2 answers. With Group by and having, the query executes in 0.0029 seconds and with your solution, the query executes in 0.0043 seconds. there is a significant  difference, sorry i mentioned 1 query in my question but what i meant was fastest, i assumed 2 query will be slower.  Thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this cannot be done with one query if you want to apply the `RAND()` ordering only for topics with 0 usage count. A possible workaround would be changing the `ORDER BY` clause like this:

```
ORDER BY u.field_topic_usage_value ASC, RAND()
```

This will apply random sorting to all topics with the same usage count as a possible workaround, while maintaining the ordering by usage count itself.